# proper way to define or modify your model in sequelize with migrations

Tags: sequelize.js

I'm a python main. I started node express project and I'm confused with commands that sequelize use for migrations.

In python flask-migrate, you write your model then doing `flask db migrate` makes a migration according to your model you've written. Then to apply your model to DB, you type `flask db upgrade` command.

But I've found that in Node.js, sequelize-cli commands are meant different. `sequelize db:migrate` actually "apply" existing migration which corresponds to `upgrade` command in python flask.

My questions is, then what is correct procedure to define or modify your model in Node.js? You have to make your model class "AND" migration script yourself then run `db:migrate` command?

It seems weird that I have to make same changes twice (Model & migration script) would there be another simple way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can avoid doing this "double work" if you bypass migrations entirely and use the sequelize.sync() method, which builds the tables from your models.

The downside of this is that when you alter your models, you will need to pass in the { force: true } flag into the .sync() method in order for the new/altered attributes to be included. This option drops your tables and rebuilds them. This is fine for development, but awkward for production.

Comment: You will lose data in production if you do this. { force: true } wipes the database on everytime the app restarts. Always use migrations.